# Android OpenGL ES + Frame Buffer Objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

We've been using Frame Buffer Objects in our application, and trying to port it to android.

However it seems that the FBO extension isn't implemented in Android 1.4 (which we are using).

We essentially need to render a scene to a texture, we don't need z-buffer, just general poly and texturing primatives.

Any suggestions on how to get round the problem?

Regards,
nash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no way around it until android moves to a OpenGL ES 1.1 implementation.
it has the proper interfaces right now , but they are not implemented. (or just partially).